# A little issue with Paypal Express Checkout with Paypal In-Context

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the library [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and the In-Context.
When I click on the checkout button, a pop-up appears (like it should) but instead of responsive payment, it's just like the normal payment page and I have to scroll right to enter my credentials. Is there a way I can make the payment page in the pop-up responsive so it will be much more comfort?

**Update 1**

I'm testing it from my localhost. screenshot:

[In-Context PayPal](https://gyazo.com/5344071cbceb39335541a6f8f42f052c)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a layout issue of some sort as that's not what I experience [here](https://demo.paypal.com/us/navigation?merchant=bigbox&page=shoppingCart). Can you maybe submit a link to your site so I can look at it?